# Ember adding check for transition call context (route/controller)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have a common mixin/code which has a transition call

```
myCommonFn: function() {
//this.transition('someRoute') // Works if context is route
//this.transitionTo('someRoute') // Works if context is controller
}
```

Now because this function is common across multiple routes, it can either be triggered from a controller or route

My question is how do I ensure this works in both the cases? Meaning should I add a check using

```
this.constuctor() //Check if it is controller or route
```

OR
should I do a null/undefined check for

```
this.transition() OR this.transitionToRoute()
```

What is the best way to make it work in all cases ?

Answer (score 0):

If your mixin is applied everywhere, the simplest is just to check and fire.  Additionally, if you have plans to upgrade, eventually controllers are going away, so this may just be a temporary fix.

```
var transition = this.transitionTo || this.transitionToRoute;

transition.apply(this, [arg1, arg2,.....]);;
```

You also could also extend your common mixin two more times and have a base version, a controller version, and a route version where you could specify route/controller specific functionality.

Comment: Thx. Is checking for this.constructor() not recommended ?

Comment: it's a perfectly viable way of doing it, it just may not be necessary.  Additionally you may need to make sure transition isn't null if you apply the mixin to a component one day